# How can I change navigation and status bar color based on theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, themes

In my `MaterialApp`, I use the properties `theme` and `darkTheme` so that it can take advantage when the user switches their global device theme. However, I'm running into an issue where the status bar and navigation bar don't change when the user switches themes. I'm using a system of routes so I have nothing in my `home` property, I just have an `initialRoute`.

I have code like this in the initial route page:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      final MediaQueryData mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

      if (mediaQuery.platformBrightness == Brightness.dark) {
        Themes.setDarkSystemColors();
      } else {
        Themes.setLightSystemColors();
      }

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(title: "Home"),
        drawer: CustomDrawer(),
        body: SizedBox(),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

But that only works when I restart the app and when I change themes, it doesn't work. I know I probably have to rebuild `MaterialApp` but I'm not sure how to go about that. I was thinking maybe an `InheritedWidget` but I don't know. It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7gV89hnooM and https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dynamic+theme+flutter

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to use it when the device changes theme and when it does, change the status and nav bar colors.

Comment: go to the topmost level of widget tree for this theme change

Answer (score 0):

That's how I change the color of the navigation bar together with dark/light/system theme change:

```
child: Consumer<Preferences>(
          builder: (context, preferences, child) {
            var app = MaterialApp(
              title: 'dikt',
              initialRoute: '/',
              routes: {
                '/': (context) {
                  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                    systemNavigationBarColor:
                        Theme.of(context).canvasColor, // navigation bar color
                    //statusBarColor: Colors.pink, // status bar color
                  ));
                  return Lookup();
                },
              },
              themeMode: preferences.themeMode,
              theme: lightTheme,
              darkTheme: darkTheme,
            );
```

https://github.com/maxim-saplin/dikt/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Note that I'm using custom Preferences provider that allows user change theme.